# Built and referenced assembly not found with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

### Background

I have a WCF-enabled project `MyService` which has a reference to a set of models in project `MyModel` and references a running service `http://example.com/endpoint.svc`. All three projects are in the same solution.

### Issue

When I edit the Service Reference Settings in the `MyService` project I get the following error:

> Custom tool warning: The assembly 'Namespace.MyModel' could not be found.  Ensure that the assembly is referenced.  If the assembly is part of the current development project, ensure that the project has been built.

The assembly is both built and referenced.

This causes the issue that WCF generates additional classes which conflict with the existing ones in `MyModel`.

### Attempted solutions

This issue seems similar to one talked about in [this MSDN forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/06e9d364-f3bc-415f-b6e3-37e172dce502/error-adding-service-reference?forum=silverlightweb) however the suggested solution (which amounts to restarting Visual Studio and service) doesn't work.

I have also tried removing and re-adding the reference, additionally combined with a Visual Studio restart.

### TL;DR

**How can I fix this issue of WCF not being able to see the assembly?**

---

### Additional information

#### Service Reference Settings

The Service Reference Settings are set up as follows:

> - Client
>
>   - Address: `http://example.com/endpoint.svc`
>   - Access level for generated classes: `Public`
>   - Allow generation of asynchronous operations: `checked` and `Generate task-based operations`
> - Data Type
>
>   - Always generate message contracts: `unchecked`
>   - Collection type: `System.Array`
>   - Dictionary collection type: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`
>   - Reuse types in referenced assemblies: `checked` and `Reuse types in all referenced assemblies`

#### Visual Studio

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Pro Update 4 (12.0.31101.00 Update 4)

#### Project target

All are targeting x64

Comment: Have you checked that the framework targeted by the referenced library is compatible with the target framework of the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the the issue may have been that Visual Studio was using an x86 version of `svcutil` in the background rather than a x64, which the projects were built in.

Manually running `svcutil` produces the desired result:

```
svcutil ^
/reference:../bin/Namespace.MyModel.dll ^
/out:Reference.cs ^
http://example.com/endpoint.svc?wsdl ^
/namespace:"*,Namespace.MyService"
```

Comment: Is there a way to force Visual Studio to use x64 version of svcutil?

Comment: @RomanMik There *may* be in VS2015 (not looked into it) but not in previous versions, at least no obvious way.

Comment: I ended up making a powershell script to run this which I initiated on a pre-build hook.

Comment: thanks for a quick response. Would it be possible to share your script? I started a question on SO about configuring VS to use x64 version (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189110/reconfigure-visual-studio-2013-to-use-svcutil-exe-x64) I wasn't able to find on my own if it is possible at all.

Comment: @RomanMik It's very specific to the application I was working on, but basically it just constructs the above call to svcutil but with the dlls and the endpoints I needed.